# How to do Infinite scroll on the web page with storing each row data in the list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, infinite-scroll

How to scroll through each row on a web page using selenium python? Consider there are 70 rows in the page. And, there are 13 rows visible on the page at a time. I need to do an infinite scroll until the last row is visible and add the row data in the list of dictionaries where the key is the column name and the value is the actual data.

How to resolve this using Selenium and Python?

**Note: There is no pagination. It just adds the data on one page with a scrolling feature.** The data on the page comes from the defined server. If any data is received by the server, it will be added to the GUI (Client portal).

Comment: You forgot to post how you tried to solve this problem.

Comment: Which web site?  Many web sites have well-defined APIs for fetching data that does not require this kind of hackery.

Comment: @ScottHunter, I can't share the code or data here that's why just explained it in simple language. I have tried to solve it where I am fetching the rows data from the webpage. but it gives StaleElementReferenceException or TimeoutException at random locations and not scrolling till the end of the last row.

Answer (score 0):

Since the query is not very to the point, there is something I could think of

```
# Define the target element containing the rows (change the locator as needed)
rows_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.row-class')

# Scroll down and retrieve row data until the end of the page
row_data = []
while True:
    # Retrieve all rows currently visible on the page
    rows = driver.find_elements(*rows_locator)
    
    # Extract and store the data from each row in a dictionary
    for row in rows:
        # Extract the relevant data from the row and create a dictionary
        # Example: Assuming each row has "name" and "age" fields
        name = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.name-class').text
        age = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.age-class').text
        row_data.append({'name': name, 'age': age})
    
    # Scroll to the bottom of the page
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')
    
    # Wait for new rows to load
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(rows_locator))
    
    # Check if there are no more rows to load (end condition)
    if len(rows) == len(driver.find_elements(*rows_locator)):
        break

# Print the row data
for row in row_data:
    print(row)
```

In this code, I started by defining the target element locator that represents the rows you want to retrieve data from. Inside the infinite scroll loop, we retrieve the currently visible rows, extract the relevant data from each row, and store it in a dictionary. We then scroll to the bottom of the page, wait for new rows to load using explicit waits, and check if there are no more new rows to load, which serves as the exit condition for the loop.

Please adjust the rows_locator and the extraction logic according to the structure of the web page you are working with.